# FileHelperEngine Library Mapping to Datetime Exception

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I'm using the FileHelperEngine library to map text from a pipe seperated list to a object. However I am getting the following exception when trying to map the date text to a DateTime attribute

Here is the attribute in my clas

```
 [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")]
    public DateTime TheDate;
```

The date is in format - 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000

I get the following exception - Error Converting '2015-10-01 00:00:00.000' to type: 'DateTime'.  Using the format: 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'

I suspect I am using the incorrect date mask.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changeing it to:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")]
```

Note uppercase MM for months. Lowercase mm is minute.

Comment: Ahh what an idiot I am - Think I needed to take a step back and look at it again after a coffee. Thank you!